# W10 + Clion, set up error

Tags: c++, linux, windows, clion

I am trying to set up Clion on my pc. I tried both Clion and mingw and I get the same error when I point to the tool chain location. I install and uninstall all the required packages for both following the instructions and I can't get it working.

Anyone else has run into this set up issue?

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error:The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/c++.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
 Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_4ce80/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_4ce80.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_4ce80.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_4ce80.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++.exe -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_4ce80.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTC_4ce80.exe
/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cygwin_cmake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_4ce80.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++.exe -Wl,--enable-auto-import CMakeFiles/cmTC_4ce80.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_4ce80.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_4ce80.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0
c++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but cyglto_plugin.dll not found
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_4ce80.dir/build.make:98: cmTC_4ce80.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/__default__/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_4ce80/fast] Error 2
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Error:Configuration Debug
The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/c++.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
 Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_4526e/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_4526e.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_4526e.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_4526e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++.exe -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_4526e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTC_4526e.exe
/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cygwin_cmake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_4526e.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++.exe -Wl,--enable-auto-import CMakeFiles/cmTC_4526e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_4526e.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_4526e.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0
c++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but cyglto_plugin.dll not found
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_4526e.dir/build.make:98: cmTC_4526e.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_4526e/fast] Error 2
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Error:Configuration Release
The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/c++.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
 Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_0c461/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_0c461.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_0c461.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_0c461.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++.exe -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_0c461.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTC_0c461.exe
/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cygwin_cmake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_0c461.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++.exe -Wl,--enable-auto-import CMakeFiles/cmTC_0c461.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_0c461.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_0c461.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0
c++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but cyglto_plugin.dll not found
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_0c461.dir/build.make:98: cmTC_0c461.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/Release/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_0c461/fast] Error 2
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Error:Configuration RelWithDebInfo
The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/c++.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
 Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/RelWithDebInfo/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_0238e/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_0238e.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_0238e.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/RelWithDebInfo/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_0238e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++.exe -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_0238e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/RelWithDebInfo/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTC_0238e.exe
/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cygwin_cmake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_0238e.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++.exe -Wl,--enable-auto-import CMakeFiles/cmTC_0238e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_0238e.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_0238e.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0
c++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but cyglto_plugin.dll not found
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_0238e.dir/build.make:98: cmTC_0238e.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/RelWithDebInfo/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_0238e/fast] Error 2
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Error:Configuration MinSizeRel
The C++ compiler "/usr/bin/c++.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.
It fails with the following output:
 Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/MinSizeRel/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_7f6fc/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_7f6fc.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_7f6fc.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/MinSizeRel/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_7f6fc.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++.exe -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_7f6fc.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/MinSizeRel/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTC_7f6fc.exe
/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cygwin_cmake/bin/cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_7f6fc.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++.exe -Wl,--enable-auto-import CMakeFiles/cmTC_7f6fc.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_7f6fc.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_7f6fc.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0
c++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but cyglto_plugin.dll not found
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_7f6fc.dir/build.make:98: cmTC_7f6fc.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/satin/.CLion2016.2/system/cmake/generated/untitled-9502414e/9502414e/MinSizeRel/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_7f6fc/fast] Error 2
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
```

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin's C++ compiler (or probably linker) can't find `cyglto_plugin.dll` which can be part of several [Cygwin packages](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=cyglto_plugin.dll&arch=x86_64). I'm not sure how Clion works - whether it requires Cygwin to be installed or brings it in its own installer. If it requires that user installs Cygwin - verify that you have installed appropriate package and that mentioned DLL is in place.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all the packages and reinstalled them. I think when you have the options to download it allows you to download multiple versions. Which is what i did and then it causes a conflict. issue was resolved.